# Emacs and vala-mode

Tags: emacs, vala

I am using vala-mode to edit Vala code in Emacs. However, I want to change two things in vala-mode:

I want to indent with 4 spaces instead of 2 spaces (which is my Emacs default).
I want to enable auto-completion inside vala-mode.

Auto-completion works in all modes except for vala-mode, and I want the 4 spaces indentation **only** for vala-mode, not all modes. However, I don't know how to make these changes only for vala-mode.

Thank you.

Comment: I second that question. I've tried to customize some settings in vala mode by adding lambdas to vala-mode-hook, but nothing works unless I add them to c-mode-common-hook (and I don't want to do that)... This is driving me nuts... I looked into vala-mode.el (there is vala-mode-hook handling section at the bottom if it) and it looks fine to me... Any help on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(add-hook 'vala-mode-hook (lambda () (setq c-basic-offset 4)))
```

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. Also tried just (setq c-basic-offset 4), didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used `vala-mode`, but it looks like it is based on `cc-mode` so that setting `c-basic-offset` might work. For info on how to set `c-basic-offset` in a style, see the documentation at

```
(info "(ccmode)Customizing Indentation")
```

Comment: It works for me (I just installed `vala-mode` from marmalade).  You have to be sure to set c-basic-offset in the buffer where you want it to take effect in.  e.g. `M-x set-variable RET c-basic-offset RET 4 RET`, or in a hook as suggested by @legoscia.  You can see what value `c-basic-offset` has in the buffer by typing `C-h v c-basic-offset RET`.

Comment: "C-h v c-basic-offset" says it is 4. I also tried to set-variable inside the .vala file. Still not working.

Comment: What is your tab key bound to (`C-h k <tab>`)?  Perhaps it's not `c-indent-line-or-region`?  Or are you trying to indent it another way?  Perhaps an example of what vala code is not being indented properly would help.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that the indentation issue was fixed but not the auto complete feature. If you are using the `auto complete` package, then in your `init.el` or `.emacs` you can simply put:

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'vala-mode)
```

You will then have auto complete locally. Thats one way of doing it. Also there is a Yasnippet package for vala that is available in MELPA (https://github.com/gopar/vala-snippets)